# Is there an easier way to implement openid?

Tags: php, openid

I've been banging my head against the wall trying to add openid to my PHP webapp, but none of the libraries provided seem to do it in a clean and simple way.

Is there any way to implement openid SSO without being forced into more design choices than is necessary?

The janrain library - being the most popular - is also the most unwieldy, although it seems to be the only one getting significant maintenance.  Aside from lacking a clear and simple tutorial, it also imposes some strange filesystem requirements and code dependencies.

Any and all suggestions are welcome.  I realize I'm interacting with other servers and that redirects and callbacks are required.  Please bear in mind, this isn't my main complaint, I understand the nature of what I'm working with.

I just wish it was easier and more clearly laid out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using PHP5, I suggest trying [LightOpenID](http://gitorious.org/lightopenid).

Answer (score 1):

I use the Zend openid library (best of a bad bunch), but it doesn't support all the latest openid features - not found a perfect implementation yet tbh..

Answer (score 1):

[Tutorial](http://qpleple.com/how-to-make-people-login-into-your-website-with-their-google-account/) describes how to implement Google login( yahoo,etc only just change the URLs, source code is same) in PHP using LightOpenID.